# Delete hashset of actions from hashset of actions

Tags: c#

I have two hashsets of `Action` how can I delete all the identical actions if they appear in the second hashset of actions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the `ExceptWith` method.

Comment: Wouldn't it produce a different result for Action though? Time for some experimentin'

Comment: @user2578333: That depends on your equality provider.  Do you mean the `Action` delegate?

Comment: Yes, it seems that I need to compare it in a different manner.

Comment: @user2578333: What kind of delegates?

Comment: Both are delegate System.Action

Comment: No; what kind of delegates are you creating? Lambdas? Directly-bound methods? Compiled expression trees?

Comment: I have no idea, I create them like this: `Program.SqlHandler.WebActions.Add(() => Program.SqlHandler.InsertWebMsg(Program.CurrentGame, Program.LastBet, Tex, Val, BetType, Address ));`

Comment: @user2578333: That's a lambda expression.  Each time you write that, you get a different delegate instance, with a different closure in its `Target` property.  There is no way to consider those equal, unless you compare `Method` alone (with a custom `IEqualityComparer<Action>`).  See also http://blog.slaks.net/2011/06/delegates-vs-function-pointers-part-4-c.html/

Comment: I would never compare them to anything but themselves, so essentially I have a looper that loops over hashset 1 and processed delegates and writes down all the processed delegates to hashset 2, at the end of this process I want to subtract hashset 2 from hashset 1 since not all hashset 1 actions are processed every time.

Comment: @user2578333: If it's the same delegate instance, that should work.